# How does an app's core-data get lost when it is updated

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

My app's users have reported their data got lost when they updated to a new version. The update has nothing to do with Coredata (nothing's changed about it). So, I'm really puzzled why they experience that. I would like your input so I get a clue where I should start looking. I personally have never experienced the data loss on my device, but I am using my app directly installed from Xcode.

```
 // MARK: - Core Data stack


 func getManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
     if managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator == nil {
         let coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = getPersistentStoreCoordinator()
         managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
     }
     return managedObjectContext 
 }


 func getManagedObjectModel() -> NSManagedObjectModel {

     guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension:"momd") else {
         fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
     }
     return NSManagedObjectModel.init(contentsOf: modelURL)! 
 }


 func getPersistentStoreCoordinator() -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
     guard let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
    fatalError("Unable to resolve document directory")
     }
     let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
     if managedObjectModel == nil {
         managedObjectModel = getManagedObjectModel()
     }
     let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.init(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)
     do {
         // MAIN LINE OF CODE TO ADD
         let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

         try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: mOptions)
         //The callback block is expected to complete the User Interface and therefore should be presented back on the main queue so that the user interface does not need to be concerned with which queue this call is coming from.
         return persistentStoreCoordinator
     } catch {
         fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
     } 
 }



 func saveCoreData (managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {

     DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
         if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        
             var saveDebugTextWhenDone = false
             do {
                 try managedObjectContext.save()
                 if self.currentParentRecordNameNeedsUpdate {
                     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("cloudUpdatedCoreDataCurrentParentRecordName"), object: self)
                self.currentParentRecordNameNeedsUpdate = false
                 }

             } catch {
                 // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                 // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                 let nserror = error as NSError
             }
         }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: The only thing there that would cause this problem would be if the store filename `Model.sqlite` changed, or if `docURL` was different for some reason. Did it work OK when you tested updating the app?

Comment: I've never renamed Model.sqlite, at least not that I can remember. I don't remember ever modifying docURL either. And, updating the app on my device (via Xcode) works without a problem. Somehow my users (at least two) have experienced data loss, so I have no clue where to start.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted here that would cause that.

Comment: Thanks for checking my code. I have other view controllers referring to managedObjectContext made in above code in AppDelegate. I will check if there's anything wrong there.